# PHP PDO Bit(1) returns wrong data type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqldatatypes

When I run this query with PDO to a mysql db it returns wrong datatypes.

```
<?php
$parameters = array(":1",92323);

$query = " SELECT s.Site_ID,s.Site_Url,s.Site_Name, s.Site_Approved, s.Site_Status, s.Thumbnailed ,st.Description AS Site_Status_Desc 
FROM Sites s
LEFT JOIN Sites_Status st ON st.Status_ID = s.Site_Status
WHERE s.Account_ID = :1";

try {

    $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db}", $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

    $this->stmt = $this->DBH->prepare($query);


    if(count($parameters)>0) {

        foreach ($parameters as $key => $var) {

            switch ($var) {
                case is_int( $var ):
                    $this->stmt->bindValue($key,$var, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    break;
                case is_bool( $var ):
                    $this->stmt->bindValue($key,$var, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
                    break;
                case is_null( $var ):
                    $this->stmt->bindValue($key,$var, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    break;

                default:
                    $this->stmt->bindValue($key,$var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    break;
            }


        }

    }

    if($this->stmt->execute()) {

        // Set how many rows the query resulted in
        $this->num_rows = $this->stmt->rowCount();

        return $this->stmt->fetchObject();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->error_handler($e);
}
```

All rows becomes strings as data types, except the BIT field, it becomes something different...

```
public 'Site_Approved' => string '�' (length=1)
```

Is there a dynamic way to make PDO return correct data types ?

Comment: The binary datatype in PHP is string. Does not seem "uncorrect".

Answer (score 10):

You're using a Bit(1) field to represent a boolean value (`TRUE`/`FALSE`).

The database client maps bit fields (which can be larger than one bit) onto strings in which one character represents an Octet.

You can than just use your Bit(1) field as PHP string via the `ord()` function as it treats the string as a single Octet:

```
if (ord($Site_Approved)) {
     ...
}
```

You can't use `$Site_Approved` directly because it's a string and it would always evaluate to `TRUE` regardless if it's first bit is set or not.

Alternatively, you can cast the database value in the SQL query already to a decimal which might be what you're looking for:

```
s.Site_Approved+0 AS Site_Approved
```

Decimal values in the range of 0 to 1 behave very similar to PHP's booleans (they just don't share the type, the rest is the same).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this explains a lot. I will change the database layout. Should a tinyint be a good substitute for the BIT?

Comment: Depends on what you represent with that column. What is `Site_Approved`? A boolean? A collection of flags? Maybe ENUM is what you're looking for, maybe BOOLEAN, maybe an INTEGER value. Depends on what you want to express.

Comment: Thank you.  This was messing with me today.  Had a cell I couldn't change to a more logical Bool value and this fixed it!