# Why chr(0x00) is considered as true in PHP?

Tags: php

0x00 is known to be the null character.

Then why in PHP `(bool) null` returns false, but `(bool) chr(0x00)` returns true ?

In the other hand, `(bool)intval(chr(0x00))` returns false.

The above is valid for all PHP versions between 5.4 and 7.0.0 beta2, so there must be a reason.

Edit: I'm asking this question, because I have a `bit(1)` column in MySQL, and chars 0x00 or 0x01 are returned.

`if ($test['bit1column'])` will always pass, because both chars are considered as true, so I'm forced to do an `if ($test['bit1column'] === chr(0x01))`.

This is correct at least for PHP 5.6 with MySQL 5.5.44.
Why? I can't see any logic here.

Comment: Because 0x00 is a character, and thats what chr returns. But it is not an intval, so thats why it would be false.

Comment: It's just a non-empty string. And its content doesn't amount to a decimal zero.

Comment: Yes, but for example when using bit(1) column in MySQL, 0x00 or 0x01 is returned. Then `if($test['bit1column'])` will always pass, because both chars are considered as true. This is correct at least for PHP 5.6 with MySQL 5.5.44.

Comment: No, `bit(1)` is [a numeric field type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html), so it returns `0` or `1`, not a character.

Comment: Because PHP is quirky.

Comment: It's because PHP was designed the way it was designed: the only two falsy string values are `''` and `'0'`, period. One can also wonder, for example, why '0.0' string is considered truthy.

Comment: No, `(bool)'0.0'` is `true`. And for `bit(1)`, you probably use the MySQL driver incorrectly…

Comment: If you can't execute a simple statement, I give up. Good continuation.

Comment: @Blackhole: you're right about the `'0.00'`, but still I'm receiving `string(1) "\000"` and `string(1) ""` from the database, not `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: I suspect that there is some confusion between `mysql bit fields` and how they are represented in PHP. I suggest that you may have to 'look after' them explicitly Maybe useful: [PHP PDO Bit(1) returns wrong data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665475/php-pdo-bit1-returns-wrong-data-type)? I suggest that the null and character issues are 'red herrings'? You need to process 'bit fields' from the database reliably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then why in PHP (bool) null returns false, but (bool) chr(0x00) returns true ?

it's because `chr(0x00)` gives you a one char long string:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(chr(0x00));"

string(1) ""
```

and then ([as per documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)) the only case string can give `false` when casted to boolean is either the empty one (so length is 0) or the string holding "0" as its content:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"

This is neither the case here as our string is not holding `0` nor is empty as it holds 1 character. So it cannot be `false` and therefore is `true`.

**EDIT**

I assume you expected `C`/`C++` like behaviour where strings are `0x00` terminated. This is not the case in PHP.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin. It seems to be an issue in the language like the '0.00' => true etc. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the following things are `false`:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `null`
- `false`
- `array()` (an empty array)

**Everything else is `true`.** `chr(0x00)` results in a string with a single character (the `NUL` byte). That's not an empty string and not a string with the character `0`, so it does not qualify as `false`.

Trying to cast the string `"\0"` (`NUL` byte) to an `int` results in `0`, because there's no parseable integer in the string, so the result is `0`. `0` is `false`.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but [a link to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) is a necessity. Strange coming from a 250k rep user.